# Delete app from page callback

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a page tab app, and I'd like to notified when peope delete it from their Page. Not looking for a deauthorize callback - I'm finding people delete the app, but don't deauthorize.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't have this information from Facebook.

Comment: I think L-P is correct, there is no callback for this. If you really need it, log the enhancement request at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.